What is wrong with the function
CREATE FUNCTION MAX(v1 integer, v2 integer)
 RETURNS integer AS $$
BEGIN
 IF (v1>v2) THEN
  RETURN v1;
 ELSE
 RETURN v2;
 END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

Error message:
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "IF"
LINE 13:  IF (v1>v2) THEN
